# AngularJS - Practices for switching context in a sliding menu?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've written a sandbox of what I am talking about here: http://jsfiddle.net/smgd6z4k/51/

I'm new to AngularJS and I want to be able to take advantage of what is available.
I made a context menu and I would like to switch the context of the menu depending on which option has been clicked. I suppose this is an organization question.

I have a persistent "slider" which updates its contents based on what "option" button is clicked. I would like each option to populate the slider using html, so I can stylize specific menus.

To populate the "slider" should I:

1) Clear the slider and insert a directive that contains the links on click.

E.G. Clicking on "Option 1" clears the slider and inserts an option-1 directive, which contains all the links.

2) Store options html in a string within a hash table and map a click to an html string.

```
var opt1 = ["Opt 1, Sub 1"];
var opt2 = ["Opt 2, Sub 1", "Opt 2, Sub 2"];
var opt3 = ["Opt 3, Sub 1"];
var opt4 = ["Opt 4, Sub 1", "Opt 4, Sub 2"];
```

I have a terrible case table that changes the context by pointing to a different array, and then iterating through that array. Not ideal.

```
switch (e) {
        case "Option 1":
            display = opt1;
            break;
        case "Option 2":
            display = opt2;
            break;
        case "Option 3":
            display = opt3;
            break;
        case "Option 4":
            display = opt4;
            break;
        default:
            display = opt1;
            break;
    }
```

3) Other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.menu.root = {
    title: 'root',
    items: [
        {
            title: 'Option 1',
            items: [
                { title: 'Sub 1' }
            ]
        },
        {
            title: 'Option 2',
            items: [
                { title: 'Sub 1' },
                { title: 'Sub 2' }
            ]
        },
        {
            title: 'Option 3',
            items: [
                { title: 'Sub 1' }
            ]
        },
        {
            title: 'Option 4',
            items: [
                { title: 'Sub 1' },
                { title: 'Sub 2' }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

$scope.menu.current = $scope.menu.root;
```

You can populate your slider with a for in the $scope.menu.current and change the current from root to one of the items. This allow you to have more levels and update the slider just by edit the $scope.menu.root object.